# Start Activity With out bluetooth

Tags: android

I have create an application to run connect to HC-06 module.and also there is brodcastlistener which listen to specific SMS and generate notification from my app.when I clicked the notification then it should load application activity.But my app always run while connect to bluetooth.But when click on notification i want to start an activity in same application .how could I do this??

Comment: hook up a pendingintent as contentIntent to the notification

Comment: what happen when we implemet pendingintent  can you please share a link

Comment: try searching yourself next time https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html#click

Answer (score 0):

```
  NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class);

    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            notificationIntent, 0);

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```